# Prefill form elements and post

Tags: asp.net, http-post

We have third party applications I need to link from my application. Where for those third part web sites I have user name and password with us (They are public websites). When the user click on those links we need to prefill user name and password and submit the form. Like single sign on kind of experience for the user. Is anyone tried doing this how we can do it. We need to open the web page with in Iframe or with in DEV ?

ASP.NET, Jquery and Java Script our platform.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting the login page into my project and towards the end with jquery I posted the form filling the the user name and password. Not good solution but it works well